# extract string of random length after a defined pattern

Tags: regex, grep

Here is the text I want to extract info from:

```
  <ul class="disc">
            <li><strong>euro195.com</strong></li>
            <li><strong>euro213.com</strong></li>
            <li><strong>uk180.com</strong> <span class="red">(optimized for web surfing; no p2p downloading)</span></li>
            <li><strong>us1.com</strong> <span class="red">(optimized for web surfing; no p2p downloading)</span></li>
            <li><strong>us2.com</strong> <span class="red">(optimized for web surfing; no p2p downloading)</span></li>
            <li>Username:   <strong>user1</strong></li>
            <li>Password:   <strong>pswd1</strong></li>
        </ul>

        <div><strong><span class="green"> More servers coming.</span></strong></div>

    </div><!-- .columns -->
```

From this text, username and password should be fetched in the following 2 ways:

1.

Username:user1

pswd:pswd1

2.

user1

pswd1

================

1.
I only can have

```
<li>Username:   <strong>user1</strong></li>
  <li>Password:   <strong>pswd1</strong></li>
```

with the following

```
egrep 'Username|Password' file
```

or this

```
<li>Username:   <strong>user1

<li>Password:   <strong>pswd1
```

with the following

```
grep -oP 'Username:.{0,16}|Password:.{0,16}' file
```

but this implies that the info length are always the same which is not the case.

2.
Here is what I tried, in vain again:

```
grep -oP "(?<=(Username: \<strong\>|Password: \<strong\>))[^>]*\<" text4
```

thanx a lot for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is a good job for grep, but you can use

```
cat text4 | egrep '(Username:|Password:)' | sed 's/^.*<strong>\(.*\)<\/strong>.*$/\1/'
```

Comment: any idea to have : Username:user1 Password:pswd1

Comment: `cat text4 | egrep '(Username:|Password:)' | sed 's/^.*\(Username:\|Password:\).*<strong>\(.*\)<\/strong>.*$/\1\2/'`

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use an html parser rather than grep.

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=(Username:   <strong>|Password:   <strong>))[^<]*" file
user1
pswd1
```

You need to add the exact spaces in the lookbehind otherwise it won't work and don't need to escape `<` or `>`.

Comment: thanx Avinash, your solution rocks again; any idea to have both

Comment: both Username:user1   Password:pswd1

Comment: @user2945546 try this command `grep -oP "(?<=(Username:   <strong>|Password:   <strong>))[^<]*" file | awk 'NR==1{print "Username:"$0;} NR==2{print "Password:"$0;}'`